# Reverse for 'about_abc' with arguments '('',)' not found

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I am trying to set up web app. I am having issues with passing host_id to template .html file

i get:

```
Reverse for 'about_abc' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['itpassed\\/(?P<host_id>[0-9]+)\\/about\\/$']
```

**inter.html**

```
<li><a href="{% url 'about_abc' host_id %}">about</a></li>
```

When i use "1" instead of "host_id" its working, but it can't stay hardcoded like this.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import warnings
import requests
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from .models import Host
[...]

def inter(request, host_id):
    return render(request, 'itpassed/inter.html')

def about_abc(request, host_id):
    response = requests.get(
        'abc.net:1768/abc/api/v1/about',
        verify='/cert/cacerts.pem',
        headers={'Accept': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'},
    )
    return HttpResponse(response.content)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .models import Host
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<int:host_id>/', views.inter, name='inter'),
    path('<int:host_id>/about/', views.about_abc, name='about_abc'),
]
```

How to fix this? As far as i can see views.py should pass host_id to template.
Why hardcoded "1" works but, host_id don't?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def inter(request, host_id):
    return render(request, 'itpassed/inter.html')
```

You are not passing anything to the `inter.html` template here - so the `host_id` template variable won't hold any value.

I believe you want this instead:

```
def inter(request, host_id):
    return render(request, 'itpassed/inter.html', {"host_id": host_id})
```